# wso2 api manager TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am feaced following error in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 devportal, but when call By postman or Curl insecure, it's ok.

```
wso2 api manager TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource
```

And in browser

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, web browsers apply the same-origin policy to avoid interactions between different origins. CORS defines a way in which a browser and a server can interact to determine whether or not it is safe to allow the cross-origin requests. That's why you have received the below mentioned error in the browser.

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource`

You can solve this in two methods. Those are as follows.

1. Enable CORS globally
2. Enable CORS per API

**Enable CORS globally**

As the title says, you can enable/disbale the CORS configuration globally which will be applied to all the APIs. You can achieve this by adding the following configuration in the **/repository/conf/deployment.toml** file. CORS configuration is enabled by default.

```
[apim.cors]
enable = true
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey","testkey"]
allow_credentials = false
```

After this configuration is applied in the API Gateway, it will affect all the API calls served by the Gateway.

**Enable CORS per API**

You can enable/disable the CORS configurations via publisher portal as well.
For that **login to publisher portal --> select the API --> Runtime configuration --> Enable the toggele button under CORS Configuration to enable CORS for the API**.

**Note:** You need to enable CORS globally before you enable CORS Per API.

[image]

When creating a new API by using a Swagger or Open API definition, CORS can be set up by defining an API-M supported Open API extension **“x-wso2-cors”**.

```
x-wso2-cors: 
    corsConfigurationEnabled: true
    accessControlAllowOrigins: 
        - "*"
    accessControlAllowCredentials: false
    accessControlAllowHeaders: 
        - "authorization"
        - "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        - "Content-Type"
        - "SOAPAction"
        - "apikey"
    accessControlAllowMethods: 
        - "GET"
        - "PUT"
        - "POST"
        - "DELETE"
        - "PATCH"
        - "OPTIONS"
```

Answer (score 0):

In publisher `portal > Runtime Configuration` :

enable CROS configuration